# How to make hair rotating in the same direction

Tags: particles, hair, instances

I the topic isn't really accurate let me explain.

You can see on the screen shot all my bees are a particle system based on hair and I wonder if there is a way to make all the bees rotate on their Z axis to converge towards the dj set.

Thanks in advance for any answers[image: scene showing random rotation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create a *Force Field > Force* (keep the strength rather low, here 1):

[image]

Comment: Thanks your a life saver ! ;) have a nice day !

Comment: Wait there is a problem, this technique seems to work only with meshes as hair and not collection but my bee is made of several meshes that I regroup on the same collection

Comment: it works fine for collections as well from what I see, you could also try to Particle Edit

Comment: its strange it works but when you hit rotation : none for collection it stops then it doesn't do it again so mystere but i've found a solution for my rotation issue so thanks again ;)